# Bash скрипт подставляет лишние кавычки

Tags: bash

создал bash скрипт test.sh

```
!/bin/bash
ls --hide="$1"
```

создал файл
touch 'ddd 1'
и запускаю мой скрипт с трейсом
bash -x ./test.sh "ddd 1"

результат 
все работает как и ожидалось, файл "ddd 1" не отоббражает, но вот трейс показывает что выполнялась команда

```
ls '--hide=ddd 1'
```

я удивился и проверил выполнить именно эту команду, и она работает

Вопрос, почему работает
`ls '--hide=ddd 1'` также как и `ls --hide='ddd 1'`
и почему баш при коде `ls --hide="$1"` преобразовал именно в `ls '--hide=ddd 1'`

Comment: Если приведённый листинг bash-скрипта правильный то я непредставляю откуда может появиться кавычка перед `--where`. Подозреваю какую-то потешную ошибку вроде «правлю один скрипт, а запускаю другой».

Comment: ну ошибки вроде "правлю один, а запускаю другой" точно не может быть, такак эксперементирую со скрыптом по разному, разные комбинации кавычек, и скипт явно реагирует :)

Comment: У меня ваш вариант скрипта работает без проблем и лишних кавычек.

Comment: @duhon в том-то и прелесть дурацких ошибок, они могут быть какими угодно. Запуск не того скрипта это всего-лишь один из вариантов.

Comment: баш никаких кавычек никуда не подставляет) ему тупо плевать что вы там написали :)

Comment: оказалось все очень даже прикольно
проверяем
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
cat > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
ls --hide="$1"
chmod +x test.sh
touch 'ddd 1'
bash -x ./test.sh "ddd 1"

Comment: @duhon, и чему именно мы должны удивиться?

Comment: @duhon, идея полностью заменять текст одного вопроса другим -- в корне порочная.

Просто прочтите ответы/комментарии и сопоставьте с видимым в настоящее время текстом вопроса и все станет ясно.

IMHO в подобном случае надо или открывать новый вопрос или делать добавления в конец текущего. Например:

       старый текст

       **UPDATE**
       новый текст
       ...

--

По делу, про подстановки и формат отладочной выдачи `bash -x ...`, на который Вы ссылаетесь, говоря о том, что "bash подставляет кавычки" постараюсь ответить позже 

(сейчас занят).

Comment: @avp, да я знаю что плохо было менять весь текст вопроса, это уже привычка из багтрекеров, в истории должен сохранить только хороший вопрос без лишней предыстории. Но я учту и впредь буду создавать новый вопрос :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачка решилась просто заменив в скрипте равно на пробел `--where="$1" === --where "$1"`
но почему такое странное поведение я так и не понял

Comment: Возможно тут дело в том, как именно команда `mysqldump` разбирает свои аргументы (в частности имнно longopt --where) и интерференции с их разбором в `bash` (перед вызовом mysqldump).

О принятых в \*nix правилах задания аргументов можно почитать в http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments

Понятно, что когда Вы пишете в командной строке

    scr "1 2 3"

то внутри scr при раскрытии `$1` кавычки пропадут. Т.е. в первом случае получаем

    ... --where=1 2 3 --no-create

а во втором

    ... --where 1 2 3 --no-create

Места мало, но идея очевидна

Answer (score 2):

[[@duhon](/users/19768/duhon)](/users/19768/duhon), когда Вы видите текст

```
 + ls '--hide=ddd 1'
```

то апострофы вокруг *аргументов с пробелами* bash просто добавляет *при печати*, на самом деле к аргументу `ls` они никакого отношения не имеют.

Попробуйте `sh -x test.sh 'ddd 1'` и увидите на экране

```
 + ls --hide=ddd 1
```

что вводит в заблуждение, т.к. ls все равно вызывается с одним аргументом - `ddd 1`, содержащим пробел, а не с двумя - `ddd` и `1`.

Теперь:

```
почему работает ls '--hide=ddd 1' также как и ls --hide='ddd 1'
```

потому что на самом деле это одно и то же -- аргумент **одно слово с пробелом**

```
--hide=ddd 1
```

Comment: все хорошо, но хотелось бы  еще ссылки на мануалы

Comment: @duhon: `man bash` вам в помощь. Там самая полная документация (хотя многовато, да). Посмотрите, например, раздел Word Splitting.